# How does a web server and database server work together?

Tags: database, webserver

How does a web server and database server work together to provide the necessary services and information to the client's web browser?

Originally, I thought the database and the web server were one and the same (that is, I thought the database was on the web server); but apparently they're separate entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is verrrrrry open ended, but I think you will find the following helpful.  For this I will be using PHP and MySQL references, but there are many out there.

Your second question first:  They are separate services that can, but don't have to be, on the same hardware.  If you are on Linux, this is often referred to as the [LAMP stack](https://www.google.com/search?q=LAMP%20stack&aq=f&oq=LAMP%20stack&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2j62l2.2570j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) (Linux Apache MySQL PHP)

As far as the actual integration, this is done with SQL queries, that are [run using PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).  The result of those queries is then parsed and formatted, also using PHP.  That result is then passed to your web browser using HTML.

Like I said, very open ended, but this should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: Thank you. So when a user, say, submits an input form, that data is inserted into MySQL through PHP, which is interpreted on the database server. Then, the resulting webpage is sent to the webserver, which is then sent to the web browser. Did I get it right?

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language, so the call to run it is sent through Apache, but it runs separate from both.  [this](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_does_Apache_MySQL_and_PHP_work_together) should help

Comment: Thanks, that was an immense help!